# Higcharts - How to remove groupPadding from the beginning of the chart

Tags: highcharts, padding, axis

I have a simple bar chart, and I wanted to shorten X-axis plotline, so it starts from the first bar. When I set group/pointPadding it applies to all bars in my chart, but I'm looking for property that controls individually first and last bar. Please advise
Addittion: My initial intention was to control title.margin property, and set spacing between title and first bar, but in reality based of number of series it sets spacing between title and beginning of xaxis plotline. I've tried to go to postrender and shorten plotline so it matches first/last bar, but in this case spacing from plotline still remains(even though plotline is not visible). Is there any way to control it? Please help!

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
        text: 'Title',
      margin: 0,
    }, 
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
          /*   pointPadding: 0.1,
            groupPadding: 0.2, */
            shadow: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/fmwdpqoL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `xAxis.tickmarkPlacement` and `series.pointPlacement` to `'on'` and clear paddings by `min` and `max` properties:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
    min: -0.2,
    max: 2.2,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},

series: [{
    data: [...],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j9h6w8t5/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min